# how to process multiple sockets in the same order as it got triggered

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I have a requirement where i have to monitor multiple sockets using poll or epoll or select. But the order in which sockets are read is critical in my case.  i have to process the socket in the same order in which it is triggered.

with select() and poll() order is not guaranteed, since we have to iterate through all the sockets and find which one is ready.

i know that epoll returns only the list of descriptors which triggered the events. But is the order guaranteed here?

More info - i am using netlink sockets to listen for various updates from kernel. I opened different sockets for arp update, route update and interface related update. If the sockets are not read in the same order how kernel sent, i face different problems.(ex- processing route delete message before i receive interface down message)

Comment: Possibly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Might be worth explaining the larger context of the problem you are trying to solve in case has a better/different way to solve it.

Comment: I think the answer in your specific use case is to use **one** `NETLINK_ROUTE` socket.

Comment: Even if `epoll` does make some guarantee about the order in which events are raised.... netlink sockets typically return multiple messages per recv call, hence the use of `NLMSG_NEXT` and `NLMSG_DONE` macros.  So multiple messages within `recvmsg` call might be "out of order" even if you service all the sockets in order.   My only other advice is to go see what "NetworkManager" does, as its probably the most widely used long-running process that uses netlink sockets to that extent.

Comment: I agree with @BrianMcFarland. Use one socket. Then you can't possibly get out of order. If you must use multiples, you would have to use threads, not `select()/poll()/epoll(),` but even then the order isn't guaranteed. You may need to rethink your requirement.

Comment: @Brian - Thanks. Where can i find networkmanager source code.

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager - I am not a lawyer.... but please note/respect that the project is GPL if using excerpts from this in a commercial setting.